# Function returning 2 values - callback issue?

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js

I am working on a push notification server (based on NodeJS) that stores data in a MS SQL database. One of the functions I need is to check if a device already has been registered in my database. I coded that like this - console information for debugging purpose:

```
function deviceExists(devicetoken, shopguid) {
    sql.connect(config, function(err) {

        if (err) {
            console.log('Error: ' + err);
        }
        else {
            var request = new sql.Request();
            request.query("select top 1 devicetoken from notifications where devicetoken='" + devicetoken + "' and shopguid='" + shopguid + "'", function(err, recordset) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('Error: ' + err);
                }
                else {
                    console.log('Records: ' + recordset.length)
                    if (recordset.length === 0) {
                       console.log('recordset.length === 0, returning false device does not exist');
                       return false;
                    } else {
                       console.log('recordset.length !== 0, returning true device does exist');
                       return true;
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    });
    console.log("Something went wrong, return true");
    return true;
}
```

What happens is that I always get to return values. First the true from the end of the function and then the true or false from where I checked the recordset length. I think I am running into a callback issue, but I don't know how to solve it.

I spend too long to get this to work, it must be my limited JavaScript knowledge that is blocking me to get it to work. I hope someone can help.

Comment: You aren't actually using a callback in you deviceExists function. You connect to the sql db, then promptly console.log(), then return true before your queries are finished.

Comment: Okay, so I am not using a callback. Thank you! Should I use one? and if yes, can you guide me to information how to use a callback in this situation.

However, when I call the function I always get 2 return values: First is always true, the second is either true or false. However, at the 2nd return my code is already in a state where the return value of the first return has been handled.

Comment: The fundamental problem is that the `return` values from those callback functions you pass into the database routines have absolutely no effect. It's an asynchronous system, and the mechanism that calls your callback functions throws away all return values.

Comment: The general guideline I use is: If I'm using a function (like a db query) that uses a callback, then my function will need one too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of using async function calls inside of your own functions:

```
function someFunc( data1, data2, callback ) {

    db.query("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id=?", [data1], function( err, results ) {
        callback( results );
    }); 

}
```

See what's happening there?  My function, 'someFunc' won't return anything, it's up to the callback object (which is a function) to return the results after the db query inline-function callback is finished.

It's would be used like so:

```
someFunc( 32, 54, function ( results ) {
    // results contains the results of the db query
    results.forEach (...);
});
```

Comment: Thank you Chris, with your help I have been able to solve this problem. Following your answer I have removed the return value at the end of the function and moved the code where query results are available to a callback function.